# Unexpected reversal of values when using a function to provide int arguments for constructor

Tags: c++

#### Background :

I am working on a toy program (Disclosure : an assignment), where I am required to make a `class A` having two integer data members. Subsequently, I am to make 3 objects of this class and make a fourth one whose data members hold the sum of the corresponding values from the first 3 objects.

The question itself was simple enough, but I made it a slightly 'fresh' way - I have a method `int getIntegerInput()` which obtains command line input from the user and returns it. I directly pass said inputs into the class constructor, which uses them to populate the member fields.

However, there was a quirk - **the values passed by me are stored in the opposite order to that in which I enter them**, messing up my calculation.

---

#### MCVE :

The most that I could simplify the code while still preseving the problem behaviour was -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getIntegerInput();

class A {
    int x;
    int y;

    public :
    A( int xValue, int yValue) {
        (*this).x = xValue; cout << (*this).x;
        (*this).y = yValue; cout <<(*this).y;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a( getIntegerInput(), getIntegerInput() );
    return 0;
}

int getIntegerInput() {
    cout << "Enter a number:\n";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}
```

An example of the problem behavior :

```
./a.out
Enter a number:
2
Enter a number:
3
32
```

---

#### Notes :

1. Tinkering around, I found that both the following codes work fine:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   int getIntegerInput();

   int main() {
       int x, y;
       x = getIntegerInput();
       y= getIntegerInput();
       cout << "x = " << x << "\ny = " << y << "\n";
       return 0;
   }

   int getIntegerInput() {
       cout << "Enter a number:\n";
       int x;
       cin >> x;
       return x;
   }
   ```

Second code.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class A {
        int x;
        int y;

        public:
            int getX() {
                return (*this).x;
            }
            int getY() {
                return (*this).y;
            }

        A(int xValue, int yValue) {
            (*this).x = xValue;
            (*this).y = yValue;
        }
    };

    int main() {
        int x,y;
        cout << "Enter numbers";
        cin >>x;
        cin >>y;
        A a(x,y);
        cout << "x = " << a.getX() << "\ny = " << a.getY() << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

2. Just in case that's relavant, I am using g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0.

Comment: The order of function call for parameters evaluation is undefined, you cannot rely on this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ummm... So, if I am not getting this wrong, my first function call will sometimes go to first and sometimes to the second argument?

Comment: Why don't you instead collect the input, and then initialize the objects with that input?

Comment: @DevashishKaushik That's left to the particular compilers implementation. The C++ standard doesn't give any guarantees about the order of evaluation.